# Example of two subgroups $H$ and $K$ of a non-abelian group $G$ such that $HK$ is not a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I need to disprove that the set $HK$ is not a subgroup of $G$ if $G$ is non-abelian. Does anyone have a trivial or easy counterexample? I cannot think of one...

Comment: Do you men is there nonabelian $G$ and subgroups $H,K$ for which $HK$ is not a subgroup? [Your use of double negative made me ask]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider $G=S_3,H=\langle (12)\rangle$ and $K=\langle (13)\rangle$.
By product formula, $$|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}=4$$ 
If $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$, then by Lagrange's Theorem,$|HK|$ divides $|G|$, which is a contradiction.
Hence $HK$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Plus one. This is the example I chose, but the reason that the set of products is not a group is much easier: these are $\{e,(12),(13), (132)\}$, which do not make up a subgroup, for any number of reasons. Like: the violation of Lagrange, as you said; or the fact that $(13)(12)$ is not in the above list; or that the above set is not one of the easily-enumerable and easily-describable six subgroups of $S_3$.

Answer (score 2):

In the symmetric group $S_4$, you can take $H = \langle (1,2,3)\rangle$ and $K=\langle (1,4)(2,3)\rangle$ (among many other choices).  Then it's easy to check that $HK \neq KH$, so $HK$ is not a subgroup of $S_4$.  (Or, just directly check that $(1,2,4), (1,2,3)\in HK$, but $(1,2,4)\cdot(1,2,3) = (1,3)(2,4)\not\in HK$.)

Answer (score 1):

Take $G=S_3,H=\left<(1,2)\right>$ and $K=\left<(2,3)\right>$. Then $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G($each containing two elements$)$ and $$HK=\{1,(12),(23),(132)\}$$a set of size $4$. Therefore, $HK$ is not a subgroup of $G$$($by Lagrange's Theorem$)$ since $4$ does not divide $6$.